# Dynamic callback method for System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

What I am trying to do is be able to pass a function reference to another function and have it used as a callback method for a System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.

See in method D() the 'Any' parameter.

I need to be able to pass the callback method pointer or reference for the 'Any' parameter. I can't use a delegate, because that would need to be static, is that correct?

Any ideas?

```
    private void A() { /*code*/ }

    private void B() { /*code*/ }

    private void C(int i)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
                D(A());
                break;
            case 2:
                D(B());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void D(type? Any)
    { 
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(Any));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want, but WaitCallback delegates take an object as a parameter.

```
        private void A(object state)
    {
        // does one thing
    }

    private void B(object state)
    {
        // does a different thing
    }

    private void C(int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                D(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(A));
                break;
            case 2:
                D(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(B));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void D(System.Threading.WaitCallback worker)
    { 
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(worker);
    }
```

Comment: The compiler will turn `(A)` into `(new WaitCallback(A))` for you.

Comment: Yeah I'm just old school.  I like to know what's going on.  I like the var type though, saves time and just at clear.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't use a delegate, because that would need to be static, is that correct.

No that is not correct.

```
delegate void MyMethods();

class Foo
{
    void Minstance() {}
    static void Mstatic() {}

    MyMethods m1 = Minstance;  // OK
    MyMethods m2 = Mstatic;    // OK
}
```

And the following is incorrect syntax:

```
        case 1:
            D(A());  // here you call (execute) A
            break;
```

just omit the parenthesis after the method:

```
        case 1:
            D(A);    // this passes a reference to A
            break;
```

And now you have to properly define D :

```
void D(WaitCallback any)
{
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(any);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to use a delegate:

```
public void CallbackDelegate();

private void D(CallbackDelegate D)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that could help:

```
private void D(Delegate any)
        {    
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ignored => any.DynamicInvoke());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an delegate like here. Please ask me if you have any questions.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Thread.Pool.Test
{
    delegate void VoidDelegate (object obj);

    public class Delegate
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// ThreadPool Entry Point for A
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name='obj'>
        /// EventWaitHandle
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref='ArgumentException'>
        /// Is thrown when an argument passed to a method is invalid.
        /// </exception>
        private void A (object obj) {
            if (!(obj is EventWaitHandle))
                throw new ArgumentException ("Only EventWaitHandle supported!");
            A ((EventWaitHandle)obj);
        }

        private void A (EventWaitHandle handle) {
            // does one thing

            //finsihed
            handle.Set ();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// ThreadPool Entry Point for B
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name='obj'>
        /// EventWaitHandle
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref='ArgumentException'>
        /// Is thrown when an argument passed to a method is invalid.
        /// </exception>
        private void B (object obj) {
            if (!(obj is EventWaitHandle))
                throw new ArgumentException ("Only EventWaitHandle supported!");
            B ((EventWaitHandle)obj);

        }

        private void B (EventWaitHandle handle) {
            // does a different thing

            //finsihed
            handle.Set ();
        }

        private void C (int i) {
            EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent (false);
            switch (i) {
            case 1:
                D (A ,waitHandle);
                break;
            case 2:
                D (B ,waitHandle);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception ("Case not supported");
            }
            //Wait for the thread to finish
            waitHandle.WaitOne ();
        }

        private void D (VoidDelegate any, EventWaitHandle waitHandle) { 
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (new System.Threading.WaitCallback (any),waitHandle);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll need to go over this when I have some more time.